# Using GCD for notification of end of file write?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using GCD to monitor my app's docs folder for incoming files. However the problem is that my notification fires at the beginning of a file write, which causes the class that then processes that file to fail because it's looking at an incomplete file. What I would like is the notification to fire **after the file write event is completed.** I looked at the DISPATCH_VNODE definitions but none of them seem to match. How might I go about this?  I'm not too keen on low-level file system stuff, but is there a "hold" or something that's placed on a file while it's being written? If so, can I monitor for when that hold is released? Below is the method I'm using for monitoring file-system events.

```
if (_src != NULL) return;

// Fetch pathname of the directory to monitor

NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
if (!docPath) return;

// Open an event-only file descriptor associated with the directory
int dirFD = open([docPath fileSystemRepresentation], O_EVTONLY);
if (dirFD < 0) return;

// Get the main thread's serial dispatch queue (since we'll be updating the UI)
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
if (!queue)
{
    close(dirFD);
    return;
}

// Create a dispatch source to monitor the directory for writes
_src = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_VNODE,   // Watch for certain events on the VNODE spec'd by the second (handle) argument
                              dirFD,                // The handle to watch (the directory FD)
                              DISPATCH_VNODE_WRITE,     // The events to watch for on the VNODE spec'd by handle (writes)
                              queue);               // The queue to which the handler block will ultimately be dispatched
if (!_src)
{
    close(dirFD);
    return;
}

// Set the block to be submitted in response to an event
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(_src, ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"New File Added" object:nil];


    });

// Set the block to be submitted in response to source cancellation
dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(_src, ^{close(dirFD);});

// Unsuspend the source s.t. it will begin submitting blocks
dispatch_resume(_src);
```